# How to change transition times for different selectors CSS

Tags: css

I have a button that transitions color when I hover over it and when I click it. I would like to have a longer transition duration for the change when I click than when I hover? Is this possible?

This is my code:

```
.form__submit {
background-color: #f06449;
border: 2px solid #f06449;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
width: 100%;
max-width: 240px;
padding: 12px 24px;
font-size: 20px;
transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.form__submit:hover {
border-color: white;     
background-color:transparent;
}

.form__submit:active {
border-color: #f06449;
color: #f06449;
}
```

I couldn't find the answer anywhere online.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you used `transition: all 300ms ease`. This means that all `properties`, `pseudo-classes` (since it is the parent), etc... will have the same transition. To do what you want to do you need to use transition in specific states, specifying the properties you want to transition (You can also use `transition: all`, as long as you don't use it in the parent class).

```css
.form__submit {
  background-color: #f06449;
  border: 2px solid #f06449;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 240px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.form__submit:hover {
  border-color: white;     
  background-color:transparent;
  transition: border-color 300ms ease, background-color 300ms ease;
}

.form__submit:active {
  border-color: #f06449;
  color: #f06449;
  transition: border-color 5000ms ease, background-color 5000ms ease;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="form__submit">
    
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```